# Create generic instance inside a method

Tags: java, generics, methods

I call a method with a generic return type like this:

```
public static <T extends HotelBean> List<T> fill(Class<T> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        T t = c.newInstance();
        list.add(t);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance inside this method without giving the `Class` as method paramter?  (`Class<T> c`)

Comment: Probably not in a method like this due to type erasure. There's also no way for the compiler to infer the actual type of `T`. The only way to get rid of the parameter would be to have the type of `T` be defined in some reflection data, i.e. a field definition or class with a concrete type. That, however, would probably contradict the purpose of your method or at least not be easier than passing a parameter.

Comment: No, generic types are erased (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so only thing which Java could use at runtime to determine type of instance it should create comes from `Class`.

Comment: You could also pass a ```Supplier<T>``` instead, using a ```MyType::new``` method reference as an argument. That would at least get rid of the throws clause

Comment: @JornVernee can you provide an example for using `Supplier<T>` ? I am very interested of your solution.

Comment: @Patrick I'll make an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there is not. This is the primary reason behind having to pass `Class<T>` in the first place.

Java compiler strips generic information from the compiled classes and methods in the process known as *type erasure*. By the time the compiler is done, all `T`s become `Object`s or the lower bound type (this would correspond to `HotelBean` in your example). Without the access to `Class<T>` the method is not capable of restoring the type parameter, which is necessary to produce a new instance.

Note that your example would have to pass the desired type one way or the other, because you are populating a list of base class objects with objects that could be `HotelBean`'s subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a better way of implementaion or should I go on with this approach?

Comment: Even without type erasure the compiler would have no way of infering the type of `T` so you'd have to either use `HotelBean` which would make generics superflous or tell the method e.g. by calling it like `this.<SpecialHotelBean>fill()` - which doesn't seem preferable over `fill( SpecialHotelBean.class )`.

Comment: @Patrick I would not try inventing a different approach, because what you have is the idiomatic solution for building generic code for object creation. Other programmers reading your code would instantly recognize it, and understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Thomas This makes sense, thanks for the comment. Although there are situations when the compiler could infer the type, for example, when you assign to `List<SpecialHotelBean>` or call a method that takes `List<SpecialHotelBean>` parameter, the precise type has to be supplied in order for the method to work.

Comment: Yeah those are the situations that break due to type erasure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they are really helpful for me to produce clean and understandable code. @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a `Class` to create an instance with, which means having to deal with catching or throwing exceptions, you could pass a `Supplier<T>` instead.

[`java.util.function.Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), (a Java 8 feature), is a functional interface that has one method `get`, which returns an object of the type `T`.

Using a `Supplier<T>` would look like this:

```
public static <T extends HotelBean> List<T> fill(Supplier<T> supp) { // No more exceptions!
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        T t = supp.get();
        list.add(t);
    }
    return list;
}
```

You can pass method references that take no arguments and return an object of type `T`, as a supplier, which includes a default constructor of `T`.

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {...}
}
```

```
fill(MyClass::new);
```

The main difference with `newInstance()`, is that the object returned from a `Supplier<T>` is not necessarily a *new* object, because you don't have to necessarily pass `MyClass::new`. You could pass any method that takes no arguments and returns a `T`.